# How to use Generic Repository for SOAP in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin.forms, soap, c#-2.0

I used Generic Repository in my sample project in Xamrin form to get data  from api.
so my question is how can I make the following code  Repository for  soap webervice to become generic. so that the If you know of an example or a blog post please point me to the right direction

it is my Sample code:

```
public interface IGenericRepository
{
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, string authToken = "");
   
}
```

and impeliment interface:

```
public  class GenericRepository: IGenericRepository
{
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, string authToken = "")
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient(uri);
            string jsonResult = string.Empty;

            var responseMessage = await Policy
                .Handle<WebException>(ex =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name + " : " + ex.Message}");
                    return true;
                })
                .WaitAndRetryAsync
                (
                    5,
                    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
                )
                .ExecuteAsync(async () => await httpClient.GetAsync(uri));

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                jsonResult =
                    await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);
                return json;
            }

            if (responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden ||
                responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                throw new ServiceAuthenticationException(jsonResult);
            }

            throw new HttpRequestExceptionEx(responseMessage.StatusCode, jsonResult);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{ e.GetType().Name + " : " + e.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: without knowing anything about your SOAP service it's impossible to answer this question.  Generally speaking I'd say this would be difficult to do

Comment: Iwant to know if it is posibele, and if you have a link that can help, please help me, thanks

Comment: If you happen to be familiar with ASP.NET, then see: [ASP.NET Core: Generic Repository Pattern](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36510.asp-net-core-generic-repository-pattern.aspx). I realize you are discussing client code, not server code, but take a look at the code on that page. Its built on open-source `Entity Framework Core`, so you can probably integrate that into your app. Might be able to find someone with experience with that on some forum. I haven't used it myself, but its a possible place to start.